# Fixed header with transparent background CSS oddity

Tags: html, css, header, z-index

I've been baffled by a CSS issue with a fixed header, so I'll just jump into it.

Basically I'm using the same image fixed position for both the header and a `div` in the `body`, to make it look like a seamless background. Then as you scroll down, the content in the `div` goes under the transparent header. But something is going wrong once I scroll past the end of the `div` with the background image. I've played with `z-index`, but Chrome/Safari doesn't seem to like that. (I can only imagine how IE would handle this). Works as intended for me on Firefox 16.

Anyways, the site itself is [at www.meeker.io](http://www.meeker.io). Any help in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is wrong? What is the expected behavior, and what is actually happening?

Comment: Wrong: as I scroll past the `div` with the same background image as the header the image in the header goes blank. Expected: background image to stay in header and content further down the page to go 'underneath' it as you scroll

Comment: This is what I see in chrome http://imgur.com/j3Hwz. Header's background is still there. Div's background is still in the div container hidden on top after scrolling the page down. Background is white for sections.

Comment: You can try validating your code. I find that that sometimes fixes my discrepancies between browsers.

Comment: weird what I'm seeing in chrome is [link](http://i.imgur.com/anzYR.png) and in safari is [link](http://i.imgur.com/0jelF.png). what version of chrome are you running, @VKen? Mine was working fine until the latest chrome canary update installed itself.

Comment: Chrome Beta 23, definitely less updated than Canary. I'm glad you've found a fix already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing your css:

```
.topBar {
    background: url(bgRailsColor3.png) no-repeat top left;
}
.rails {
    background: url(bgRailsColor3.png) no-repeat top left fixed;
}
```

Comment: wow thanks that fixed the issue of the header background image disappearing after scrolling down in FF, Chrome and also Safari. But now with the header at the top of the screen the image is shrinking to fit screen width. See [link](http://i.imgur.com/K2Ib0.png). Any way to make the background image of the header stretch to align?

Comment: did you make both the changes i suggested?  when i did that in chrome dev tools, i didn't see what your image shows.  can you make the changes to the live site and i'll look at it?

Comment: Sure - they're up now. At first I thought it was fixed too, but then I closed chrome dev tools ( in the same chrome window, at the bottom) and the `div.rails` background image resized throwing off the alignment.

Comment: Try removing "background-size: cover" from both the .topBar and .rails classes.  It seems to work in Dev Tools, but I'm not sure if it's the effect your looking for.

Comment: Did the trick. For now I'm just going to stick with that because functionality-wise it works the way it should. Thanks so much for you help!